# How to connect SSH to localhost in Windows7?

Tags: ssh, localhost, openssh, user

Connect SSH Secure Shell to localhost in Windows machine.

What will be host name, username , port and authentication method filled in Quick connect of SSH?

I tried with 127.0.0.1, but it is receiving

> local host is not reachable

The following details are given to connect

[image]

Comment: what program is that, that you are using, in your screenshot?

Comment: @barlop I am using **SSH Secure Shell v3.2.9**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using is correct as 127.0.0.0/8 is always localhost and 22 is the default port for ssh, so nothing is wrong there. You should check the following: run netstat -an from the shell and ensure that port 22 is being listened on.  Since you are using the loopback interface, it should bypass the windows firewall, so you don't have to check there.

Comment: How can I check command "run netstat -an" as SSH shell doesn't allow to enter any command without connection.

Comment: From the windows command prompt (cmd).  I can't think of any reason you need to SSH to localhost except for to run some sort of test.

Comment: It's `netstat -an`, without 'run'. Which SSH server are you running and what's the purpose of connecting to localhost?

Comment: @gronostaj Want to know whether it is possible to connect. I have installed git, need to access it from SSH rather than other terminals.

Comment: There is no port with 22 is listening... How can I add there? 127.0.0.1:2559,6429 etc... are listening. When I connected with 2559, it gives error as "Connection closed by remote host".

Comment: That means whatever SSH server you have setup is not listening on the default ssh port or perhaps not even running.  Like @gronostaj asked, what SSH server have you setup?

Comment: I am using **SSH Secure Shell v3.2.9**.

Comment: It's a SSH client, not a server. You can't connect simply because SSH server isn't running on localhost. I may recommend [KPyM Telnet/SSH Server](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm).